# Добавить данные в динамический контент

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Пишу простое приложение на html и jquery. Есть страница авторизации. Форма авторизации находится внутри тега `<div id="body"></div>` Данные отправляются на сторонний сервер. После успешной авторизации содержимое страницы обновляется через метод load():

```
$("#body").load("_ListView.html",InitListPage());
```

Содержимое _ListView.html :

```
<table id="driversList" align="center">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Login</th>
    <th>Ширина</th>
    <th>Долгота</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

</tbody>

</table>
```

А вот в методе **InitListPage**  я хочу через очередной запрос к серверу подгрузить данные (строки и столбцы для table). Но jQuery не видит разметку подгруженной страницы. Не отрабатывает даже тестовый метод:

```
 $("#driversList").css("border","3px solid red");
```

Как мне выйти из этой ситуации??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ был дан [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35682882/put-data-to-dynamic-content-using-jquery)

В двух словах, надо сделать не вызов функции, а callback

```
$("#body").load("_ListView.html",InitListPage);
```

Answer (score 0):

Так работает:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>titile</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <style>

 </style>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
 <script>
  $(function(){

   $('body').load('_ListView.html', function () {
     $('th').css('backgroundColor', 'tomato'); 
   });
   
   
  });
 </script>
</head>
<body>

 

</body>
</html>
```